# R clustering PAM add country labels to clusplot

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to add country labels to a clusplot and cant seem to get the plot to display anything other than the numbers, whereas I need the respective countries to show.

Here is the line of code I am trying to work with

```
fvi.use = exampledata[,-c(1)]
medians = apply(fvi.use,2,median)
mads = apply(fvi.use,2,mad)
cars.use = scale(fvi.use,center=medians,scale=mads)
cars.dist = dist(fvi.use)
cars.hclust = hclust(cars.dist)
plot(cars.hclust,labels=exampledata$Country,main='Heirarchial clustering')

cars.pam = pam(cars.dist,5)
names(cars.pam)
clusplot(cars.pam, attr(exampledata$Country,"Labels"), labels=5)
plot(cars.pam, labels=exampledata$Country)
mosaicplot(cars.use)
clusplot(cars.pam, attr(exampledata$Country,"Labels"), labels=5)
```

example data is a matrix with a country name in the first column, and then three more columns of data I would like to do the cluster analysis on

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is cars.pam?  What is exampledata?   We cannot run your code.

Comment: Have added some more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  your description

> example data is a matrix with a country name in the first column, and then 
>   and then three more columns of data I would like to do the cluster 
>   analysis on

I assume that you want to label the *points* with country names. 
the documentation for `clusplot.default`  says

> The labels of the points are the rownames of x if x is matrix like.

So to get that, you need to set the row names to the countries that you want displayed. 
Here is an example with junk data.

```
library(cluster)

Countries = c('Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria',
    'Andorra', 'Angola','Antigua', 'Argentina',
    'Armenia',   'Aruba', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Azerbaijan')

set.seed(2017)
Data = data.frame(Countries, iris[sample(150,12), 2:4])
rownames(Data) = Countries
PAM3 =pam(Data[2:4], 3)
clusplot(PAM3, labels=3, lines=0)
```

[image: Clusplot with labeled points]